# Using same wildcard SSL Certficate on different machine

Tags: ssl-certificate

Suppose I have a wildcard ssl certificate for "*.example.com", can I use the same certificate on different machines like "qa.example.com", "pp.example.com" with different IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, with a wildcard cert, yes you can.

Wildcard certificates are generally a single certificate that can be applied to multiple servers. It would be something that you could use for QA, Dev and PP. Each server needs a certificate whether it is a wildcard one or not anyway.

Comment: added some details to your answer.